# How to edit a database over time in R?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

All I am trying to do is have a file with information on distances (in miles) between an inputted zip code and the zip codes of certain locations. I have a all of the possible inputs as the column names, and the places that you are going as the row names. I want to be able to fill in this data set as the zip codes are inputted in the app. How can I make a file that I can save when the app is closed, and will be able edit it when I run the app the next time? I have tried many ways, but I have been unable to write over a file, and renaming the file every time I fill in more information seems very inefficient.

Comment: maybe [Persistant data storage in shiny apps](http://deanattali.com/blog/shiny-persistent-data-storage/) will help

Answer (score 0):

If your planing on only having one instance of your app up and running at any time you could save the files using `wrtie.csv` and `read.csv` alternatively you can save your variables as R data using the `load` and `save` functions.

```
data <- matrix(runif(5*5),nrow=5)

# Save as .Rdata
save(file="mydata.Rdata",data)

# Load data into variable
n.env  <- new.env()
load(file="mydata.Rdata",envir=n.env)
my.dat <- n.env$data
```

If this application should support multiple users maybe it's better to have a database (SQL-lite maybe?) where you store users in one column and the data matrix in the other column using serialize [like this](http://jfaganuk.github.io/2015/01/12/storing-r-objects-in-sqlite-tables/).

```
# The database method
library(RSQLite)

db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="mydb.sqlite")

# Create table
dbSendQuery(conn = db,
  "CREATE TABLE Data (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT,
    User INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Stored BLOB,
    dim INTEGER
  );")

# Basically how this works, serialize and then unserialize
# unserialize( charToRaw(rawToChar(serialize(data, NULL, ascii=T))) )

in.data <- list("dat1"=rawToChar(serialize(data, NULL, ascii=T)), "user"="user1")

# Insert values it
dbGetPreparedQuery(db, 'INSERT INTO Data (Stored, User) VALUES (:dat1, :user)', 
                   bind.data = as.data.frame(in.data) )

# Now retrive the data again
df2     <- dbGetPreparedQuery(db, "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE User = :user", bind.data = data.frame("user"="user1") )
my.dat2 <- unserialize( charToRaw(df2$Stored[1]))
```

Hope this helps!